# Excel, how to increment row number for the SUM function?

Tags: excel

I have a Excel spreadsheet with original data in the range A1:A100

I want cell B1 to be the sum of A1:A5, B2 = sum(A6:A10), B3 = sum(A11:A15)  and so on. What formula can I use for cell B1, that allow me to copy it to others B cells to achieve the above?

Thanks and Regards,
Nhan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,4*(ROW(A1)-1),,5))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response.